# insert JSP file into other JSP file to specific div

Tags: html, jsp

Is that possible? For example, if I have my **main.jsp** that is just a container/template in which other JSP files get included, to their specific predefined places.

Something like the following:

```
<body>
        <!-- user input -->
            <!-- Insertion point for user input template -->
            <div id="user_input">I want user_input.jsp here</div>


            <!-- Insertion point for user data template -->
            <div id="user_data"> I want user_data.jsp here</div>

    </body>
```

So if I just include files **user_input.jsp** and **user_data.jsp** on the top of the page like `<%@ include file="user_input.jsp" %>` then those HTML elements won't be in place. So in **user_input.jsp** I have the HTML input form, and I want it to be exactly where the `<div id="user_input">` is.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe its time to go step deeper, in JSP frameworks, Apache Tiles and other? Seems Your problem is in this class

Comment: @JacekCz so its not possible?

Comment: @Jacek Cz not possible with just JSP?

Comment: 1 . I think is possible, but in few month developer has many pieces of chaotic code. Framework usually forces organisation . .... 2. the next popular name from JSP world is SiteMesh 3. Understand including JPS like static compilation, this not the same like in php family

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a JSP fragment (.jspf). Which can put in a fragment of JSP into a specific place in the file.

You can input a .jspf into your jsp file using this:

```
<%@ include file="/path/to/file.jspf" %>
```

To convert your .jsp files into .jspf, you just put an f at the end, and you may need to reformat your code as if you we're putting it into **main.jsp**
(eg: removing imports, remove unneccesary HTML tags...etc)

JSP fragments are just JSP files but are pretty much combined with your .jsp file, so any imports that you need you may need to do on your main.jsp.

Hope this helps